# How to save the listitems being added at client side when click the brower's back button?

Tags: asp.net, listbox, client-side, back-button

I have two ListBoxes, left one and right one, and two Buttons in between Add and Remove. I wrote javascript function for Add/Remove to add selected items from left ListBox to the right ListBox. After submit the page, I click the Back Button in the browser, the items in the right ListBox are gone. I think the reason is probably because those items were added at the client side, server didn't know. It there anyway I could save those items so that when I click the Back button, they are still inad the ListBox?

I don't want to make the Add/Remove do a postback, since loading the page takes a while. I tried to put them in a updatepanel, but not working.

Update: I put the right ListBox in an UpdatePanel, and make the Add/Remove button PostBackTrigger, it worked. But this way caused a whole page postback? Why do I need UpdatePanel then? If I make the Add/Remove AsyncPostBackTrigger, it only caused partially postback, but when I clicked the Back button, my selection was gone. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can anybody help me out here please?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you cannot handle the browser "Back" button. You can disable the Back button instead in order to avoid the situation.

Comment: I need the back button so that the custmer could go back modify his selection.

Answer (score 0):

Could the [jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) solve your problem perhaps?